# Send logs from a bucket into google cloud logging

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I have files in a bucket named : json.xxx.log.date

I would like to send them to google cloud logging

I got this code:

```
import os
import logging
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud.logging_v2 import Client

def process_file(data, context):
    """Triggered by a change to a Cloud Storage bucket.
    Args:
        data (dict): The Cloud Functions event payload.
        context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata of triggering event.
    """
    # Get the file name from the Cloud Storage event
    file_name = data['name']
    bucket_name = data['bucket']

    # Download the file to a temporary directory
    temp_dir = '/tmp'
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(file_name)
    file_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, file_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(file_path)

    # Configure the Cloud Logging client
    logging_client = Client()
    log_name = os.environ.get('LOG_NAME', 'my-log')
    logger = logging_client.logger(log_name)

    # Read the contents of the file and send them to Cloud Logging
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        log_lines = f.readlines()
        for line in log_lines:
            logger.log_text(line)

    # Remove the temporary file
    os.remove(file_path)

    # Log that the file was processed
    logging.info(f'File {file_name} processed.')
```

I launch the commande to deploy my function in a cloud shell:

```
gcloud functions deploy Logstogcl \
    --entry-point process_file \
    --runtime python39 \
    --trigger-resource XXXXX \
    --trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize \
    --set-env-vars LOG_NAME=my-log \
    --project XXXXX
```

And I have this error and only this:

```
Error building source archive from path [.]. Could not validate source files: [[Errno 2] No such file or directory: './usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rdoc/generator/template/darkfish/fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf']. Please ensure that path [.] contains function code or specify another directory with --source
```

When I try to deploy via the button "deploy" on the cloud function I have this error:

```
ERROR 2023-04-18T10:07:50.608240Z [resource.labels.functionName: sendlogs] [labels.executionId: xolrx68qq7hj] Traceback (most recent call last): File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/bin/functions-framework", line 8, in <module> sys.exit(_cli()) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__ return self.main(*args, **kwargs) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main rv = self.invoke(ctx) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke return __callback(*args, **kwargs) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/functions_framework/_cli.py", line 37, in _cli app = create_app(target, source, signature_type) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 288, in create_app spec.loader.exec_module(source_module) File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed File "/workspace/main.py", line 3, in <module> from google.cloud import logging ImportError: cannot import name 'logging' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)
  {
    "textPayload": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/bin/functions-framework\", line 8, in <module>\n    sys.exit(_cli())\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py\", line 1128, in __call__\n    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py\", line 1053, in main\n    rv = self.invoke(ctx)\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py\", line 1395, in invoke\n    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py\", line 754, in invoke\n    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/functions_framework/_cli.py\", line 37, in _cli\n    app = create_app(target, source, signature_type)\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py\", line 288, in create_app\n    spec.loader.exec_module(source_module)\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 850, in exec_module\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed\n  File \"/workspace/main.py\", line 3, in <module>\n    from google.cloud import logging\nImportError: cannot import name 'logging' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)",
    "insertId": "643e6bf6000947f0c7e093cf",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_function",
      "labels": {
        "project_id": "mdhcare-uat",
        "function_name": "sendlogs",
        "region": "europe-west1"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-04-18T10:07:50.608240Z",
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "labels": {
      "instance_id": "00c61b117c72682bd01d6d7a248a3cabc7371e0de7e22f2a65653e8cab7ecd5c1428cd00163096a293d5896381311fe794ec04d217cf84558d6270",
      "execution_id": "xolrx68qq7hj"
    },
    "logName": "projects/mdhcare-uat/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
    "trace": "projects/mdhcare-uat/traces/d7ba5c0643661eec194372634e647537",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-04-18T10:07:50.612463389Z"
  }
```

I tried to change the language, tried in `NODE.JS`

First generation too

Comment: Can you share the error logs? And i can see `ruby` in file path and you are specifying `runtime=python`. May I know the reason behind that?

Comment: The error in your post is not related to the Python code. Update your post with correct details.